# Breakpoints not triggering in VSTO Add-in

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, addin-express

I was made aware of an interesting situation by my client today. I am sure it is something simple but seems like I can't put my finger on it. Have never faced this issue and Google has not been too helpful.

**Problem**

On my client's laptop, the Add-In is created with [Add-in Express™ for Microsoft® Office and .net](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php). When running the Add-in from VS, the breakpoints do not trigger. I logged in via teamviewer. We created a new test project (Add-in) and added this simple code.

```
Private Sub AdxExcelAppEvents1_WorkbookOpen(sender As Object, hostObj As Object) Handles _
AdxExcelAppEvents1.WorkbookOpen
    MessageBox.Show ("Hello World")
End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint on `AdxExcelAppEvents1_WorkbookOpen` and ran. I got the message when I opened a new workbook but the breakpoint did not trigger.

I tested the same code on my laptop and it works just fine.

**What has he and I tried**

1. Unregister, Clean + Rebuild, Register
2. Manually cleaning the Debug folder
3. Repairing Add-In Express
4. Uninstalling/ReInstalling Add-In Express
5. Jumping between frameworks 4.5 and 4.6, 4.7.1
6. Toggling `Tools | Options | Debugging | General require source files to exactly match the original version`
7. Toggling Solution platforms (x86|64|AnyCPU)

**Applications**

1. Visual Studio Version: 2019 Pro
2. MS Office: 2016 Professional Plu 2016

Let me know if you need anything else?

**FYI**: This has been crossposted at [Add-in Express forum](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=15845) I usually do not crosspost but seems like my client is under pressure and has to deliver this project on monday morning.

Comment: An Add-in Express add-in is ***NOT*** VSTO technology. Please edit this question accordingly. Yes, both base on IDT2Extensibility, but in essence they are competing tools...

Comment: I absolutely agree with you Cindy. I added that tag because I thought someone who works with VSTO may have experienced this while creating an Add-in :)

Comment: I know nothing about Addin Express, but are you generating the "Debug Info" (Proj Propererties>Compile Tab->Advanced Compile Options button)?

Comment: Thanks @TnTinMn. It is set as `full` as usual. There are very few differences between them. I like using Add-in Express because it gives me a better control over my Add-in. My client informs me that the breakpoints were working and then Excel got stuck. He had to `End-Task` it. After that the breakpoints stopped triggering

Comment: are you sure that the add-in that is loaded by Excel is the one that you build ? It is possible that you load an old one located somewhere else. In Excel remove the addin and add it again by hand. You may also try the `Debugger.Break` from `System.Diagnostics`

Comment: @Malick: That was my thought too. And hence I tried what you said but it did not help. I also tried point 6 because of this. I also changed the message. But everytime i ran the code, the updated message showed. Also like I said, I created a new project and it happened with that as well...

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on a method before, ex: ThisAddIn.Startup, does it work ?

Comment: In Add-in Express, we do tno have `ThisAddIn.Startup`. Yes it works for `AddinModule_AddinInitialize`.

Comment: So if it works, that's great, there is a problem with your `WorkbookOpen` event, maybe a runtime error..(or a problem in add-in express - but I never use it), you can try to step in up to this event. One idea would be to open programmaticaly a worbook and to step in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210095/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-malick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [Debugger.Break](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=netframework-4.8) from `System.Diagnostics` and observe if you get more information about a plausible unhandled exception. In this case, we get the exception `wkernelbase.pdb not loaded` and Siddharth found it can be fixed by selecting : `Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols->Select "Microsoft Symbol Servers"`.

Comment: Thank you for staying with me on this! One thing I would like to add is if `Debugger.Break` fails then try `If (Debugger.IsAttached = False) Then  Debugger.Launch()`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's an *{excel}.exe.config* file in the Office folder. The .config requires all add-ins to use .NET 2.0 (3.0, 3.5).

That would explain the issue: you use .NET 2.0 (3.0, 3.5) while the debugger expects to use .NET 4.0 (4.X).

And yes, Add-in Express is built around the COM Add-in technology, not VSTO Add-in.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I do not have the config file. That was one of the few things I had ealier checked. Anyways it is sorted. It was a simple setting which had got unchecked. All good now. I have been making VSTO Add-ins for almost 12 years now. I have been testing Add-in express for the last 1 month now and I like it. :) As far as VSTO tag is concerned, the reason why I tagged it as VSTO is so that anyone who creates Add-in might have faced a similar situation or could suggest something. And that is exactly what happend. Malick helped me figure out the problem.